# converting 3 hours ago, 7 hours ago etc into unix timestamp

Tags: unix, timestamp

```
Hello Everyone
```

Can anyone guide me how i can convert 4 hours ago, 3 hours ago etc into unix timestamp? It is often observed on many sites some time ago like 3 hours ago etc , i really need it to convert into unix timestamp, let me know if anyone have any idea?

Comment: hey, that's a nice way to dodge the salutation squasher !

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, [`date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) can do this conversion for you:

```
date -d "3 hours ago" +"%s"
```

where `+"%s"` is a date format that simply means "print unix timestamp"

Answer (score 1):

if it is always in the format "n Hours ago" you can convert n to an integer and then subtract 3600*n from the current unix timestamp.

Without knowing the language you are using it is hard to give a more detailed explanation.